# Angular: pass dynamic values to nested components inside ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a child component inside a ngFor loop to which i want to send dynamic values. This is what i have tried so far, but it does not seem to work

```
<div *ngFor="let item of clientOtherDetails">

<h1>{{item.name}}<h1>

<app-child-component [firstname]="item.firstname" [secondname]="item.secondname"><app-child-component>

</div>
```

and in the child component i am using @Input() to get the values

```
@Input() firstname;
@Input() secondname;
```

I am not getting the dynamic first name and last name

Any advice will be of great help. thanks in advance

Comment: The code you wrote seems correct. Can `item.firstname` be null? Also you can monitor the values for `@Input` parameters in `ngOnChanges`.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL firstname and last name is always there. i will check ngOnchanges, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Exsite Please check my code and let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution for you. Please check my code and stackblitz link=>

**Child TS:**

```
import { Component, Input, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    First:  <input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]='firstname'><br>
    Second: <input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]='secondname'> 
  `
})
export class AppChildComponent {
  //getting value from parent to child
  @Input() firstname: string;
  @Input() secondname: string;
}
```

**Parent HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let site of sites">
  <app-child [firstname]="site.name" [secondname]="site.sname"></app-child>
</div>
```

**Parent TS:**

```
import { Component, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  sites=[{name:'aa',sname:'s-aa'},{name:'bb',sname:'s-bb'},{name:'cc',sname:'s-cc'}];
}
```

**Note:** You cam find the code in this link=> [STACKBLITZ DEMO LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction-mbfjqr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).